# Chrome - active tabs locations and starting tabs location

Tags: python, google-chrome

I was wondering where the Chrome settings file that contains the URLs of web pages to open when you start it next time is. I couldn't find a similar question here. And also note that I am not talking about multiple homepages here, if that is possible though, that is a solution I guess. Chrome has this functionality to open all the tabs that you had open, the next time you start it. Though, sometimes by mistake, you may open a new chrome instance and close the one that you had with multiple tabs (thus, next time it will open the web pages in the second instance; i.e. in the last one that you had open). So I wanted to write a python script that I could execute that allows me to do two things:

1) Save the current state of open tabs
2) Restore that state next time I open Chrome (for an extension, I may also want to append the saved web pages from 1) into currently open web-pages).

This is not difficult, I think. I just need to know, probably, two locations. **One - where the active tabs are, Two - where the starting tabs are.**

Thanks